# Purpose of findElement method in WebElement (Selenium)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am learning Selenium WebDriver and I am facing some trouble.
I am unable to get the purpose of the methods findElement,findElements in WebElement when we already have them in WebDriver. What is the difference between the methods in WebElement and WebDriver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebDriver driver;
WebElement webObject;

driver.findElement() searches for the element/s on the entire web page while webObject.findElement() searches for the element/s within the webObject object.

Example:
webObject = driver.findElement('some webtable');

webObject.findElement('some cell') :: searches for the cell within that particular table.

driver.findElement('some cell') :: searches for the cell within the entire web page.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a

```
<div id="parent">
   <a id="child">child</a>
</div>
```

You can do

```
 WebElement div = driver.findElement(By.id("parent"));
 WebElement a = div.findElement(By.id("child"));
```

so you're able to search inside the elements

Comment: This is not an appropriate answer for this question i guess!

Comment: OK, maybe I didn't get the gist of the question, why do you think its not appropriate?

Comment: because your explaining the one aspect of the `WebElement` by just providing an example without clear explanation whereas the questions is more about the significant diff of WebDriver and WebElement

Comment: could be, still I think its OK, will leave and let people up/down vote, others will land answers as well